# In Star Trek IV how does Sulu know how to fly a Huey?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, the-voyage-home

Sulu states he used to fly them in his academy days, but should we take that statement at face value? If the statement is accurate, why would he learn on hundred plus year old technology?

Today, a person might learn to operate a sailboat or single engine airplane, but a professional would learn on a modern boat/airplane and not learn how to operate an antique.

In Star Trek do any characters ever discuss learning on older technology or do we have reason to believe he had access to a manual for a 20th century Huey?

Comment: The US military operate several 'antique' boats that are used to teach seamanship; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Constitution

Comment: It could've been a hobby or club, not necessarily part of the curriculum as such. That would further explain why Sulu can fly the thing but the rest of the Academy graduates *can't*, and are surprised by it. You'd think Kirk at least would've gone through all the piloting classes he could.

Comment: I may need to edit my question - but we never see evidence of very old aircraft being used in other movies or episodes. I was wondering if this is ever explained anywhere. My speculation might be a hobby / club.

Comment: iirc Takei gives a comic double take / "uh oh!" type of look when he first hops in and orients himself with the controls- I'd have to go look to make certain

Comment: Why did this get down voted?

Quick edit, this got multiple up and down votes. Just asking for clarification.

Comment: We know he liked old guns, can old helicopters be far behind.

Comment: He accidentally turned on the windshield wipers when he was trying to figure out how to fly the thing - obviously he was just bluffing, trying to play it like he knew what he was doing so that the guy would let him borrow it.

Comment: @J... The wiper thing is of course something the audience could relate to because such is precisely what they might have experienced when first time driving a car built for the "wrong" side of the road

Comment: “should we take that statement at face value?” — Starfleet officers, famous for lying to each other.

Comment: "a professional would learn on a modern boat/airplane and not learn how to operate an antique" Most "Professional" pilots today, whether civilian or military first learn to fly on a Piper Cub (built between 1938 & 1947) or Cessna 150/152 (produced between 1958-77/1977-85). Granted, that's reasonably "modern" in GA circles. They learn on the basic, simple aircraft before advancing to more complex ones. You don't learn to drive a semi at age 6, you learn to ride a bike first.

Comment: @FreeMan 5 Even transitioning from a Cessna (150/152 or 172, have your pick) to a Piper Cub takes most pilots 10 to 15 hours or so just due to the tailwheel endorsement. A Cub and Cessna both have a yoke and rudder pedals - that certainly is true. A brand new Cessna 172 has flaps, autopilot, Glass cockpit, and GPS, which the Cub doesn’t have. I don’t know what a future Cessna will have.

A helicopter pilot may take 30 hrs to solo. 

My take is Sulu learning in a few hours is a stretch. Based on the answer posted, the writers were suggesting he picks it up quickly with no experience.

Comment: _"transitioning ... to a Piper Cub takes most pilots 10 to 15 hours or so"_ -- a) this is an exaggeration...there are no fully documented statistics, but the lower end estimate from a variety of sources is 5-7 hours, and b) the endorsement involves training and demonstration of mastery of the skill. But pretty much _any_ trained pilot would be able to depart in a tailwheel airplane, and has a decent chance (i.e. significantly better than zero) of landing without major trauma. Tailwheel endorsement isn't much of a good analog for flying helicopters, but the same principles do apply: ...

Comment: ... that is, a pilot with some knowledge of the basic issues of rotorcraft flying is likely to be able to _depart_ without too much trouble, and to successfully fly in cruise. It's the hovering and landing phases of flight that are the most challenging, and the least likely to be successfully accomplished by someone with zero training. But even there, so what? Sulu _did_ get some introductory training, he does have some aeronautical experience, and it's not like he has to be able to repeat the performance. For the sake of the storytelling, he just has to get lucky once. :)

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the lighter, simpler helicopters are generally considered more challenging to fly in many ways. A larger one like a Huey has more power and inertia, along with a more complex rotor/mast system that reduces some of the challenges found in the smaller aircraft. A Starfleet pilot, used to having to deal with the challenges of a heavier/faster craft (which generally involve having to plan ahead, take wider turns, that sort of thing) would improve their chances of successfully flying something like the Huey as opposed to, e.g. a Bell 47, R22, Schweizer 300, etc.

Comment: @Peter – Okay we’re really getting into the weeds on this one and I’m not sure we disagree that much. I decided to stop responding to this thread but here I am. My conclusion is still that it’s unrealistic to learn to fly a Huey in a few hours. The answer given is “correct” in that it clearly shows the writers’ intentions.

The reason I brought up a tailwheel endorsement is because a previous commenter brought up transitioning from a Cessna 150 to a Piper Cub. My point was even transitioning from a SEL fixed wing to another, 50 years apart would take hours. (Not to mention ground.)

Comment: ...The 10 to 15 hours was based on what an instructor told me before I got training when I was considering building a Kitfox. Google says it’s more like 5 to 10 hours. I also previously stated 30 hours to solo in a helicopter, which I got from a pilot, but Google says it’s actually 60 to 70 hours. Which is further proof not to trust helicopter pilots, am I right?

Comment: ...I think we don’t have good reference points for learning to fly the Enterprise and traveling back in time and learning to fly a Huey in the 1980’s. I spent no more than 5 minutes coming up with the following reference points using a Google search: Tailwheel endorsement 5-10 hrs. Solo SEL 10-20 hrs. Solo Helicopter 60-70 hrs. BFR after 10 years of inactivity ~10 hrs.

I'll also point out again that Sulu never needs to use his feet while flying the Enterprise. So it just seems unlikely he'd develop the coordination so quickly.

Comment: @DougSmallBerries I did it in 3 hours, without any previous tailwheel experience. 5 to 7 hours is fairly standard for the transition in my experience. But I know several pilots who did it in 3 or 4 hours like me. A lot depends on the teacher and the natural aptitude of the student. Some of the practice needs the right conditions to do (wind, landing on a "soft" field) so it is rare to do it all in one training session. That usually adds more time too. On a  second or 3rd session weeks later you may want to take a half hour to get re-acquainted with the plane.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home_(novel)) makes it clear that Sulu has never flown a helicopter, even in a simulation.

> Sulu approached the plastics company's big huey, entranced. He had seen still photos and battered old film of this helicopter, but none had survived, even in museums, to his time. The. huey was as extinct as the humpback whale. He stroked one hand along its flank.
>
> He climbed up and looked into the cockpit-incredible. Hardly any electronics at all, all the gauges and controls mechanical or hydraulic. Flying it would be like going back to horse-and-buggy days. And he had never driven a horse and buggy.

The basic principles of piloting are, however, sufficiently similar that he's able to pick up the controls in a few hours, with assistance from the helicopter's real pilot.

> "Right on." The young pilot wiped his hands on a greasy rag. "You
> fly?"
>
> "Here and there," Sulu said. He patted the helicopter's side. "I flew
> something similar to this in my Academy days."
>
> "Then this is old stuff to you."
>
> "Old, maybe. But interesting." He jumped to the ground and offered his
> hand. "I'm Sulu-with the international engineering conference tour?"
>
> The pilot shook his hand. "I didn't know about a tour. They just tell
> me fly here, fly there, don't drop the merchandise. International,
> huh? Where you from? Japan?"
>
> "Philippines," Sulu said, just to be safe. He had Japanese in his
> ancestry, but more of his family came from the Philippines, and he
> knew far more of its history.
>
> "Hey. You folks really did it. Repossessed your country. What about
> all the loot, though? Think that will ever make it home again'?"
>
> "Oh, I think so, eventually," Sulu said, trying not to sound too
> certain. He drew the conversation back to the huey. "I was hoping I'd
> find a pilot when I saw this helicopter. Mind if I ask a few
> questions?"
>
> "Fire away."
>
> They chatted about the copter for a while. The pilot glanced at his
> watch. "I've got to make a delivery," he said. "Want to come along?"
>
> "I'd like nothing better."
>
> The chopper lifted off in an incredible clatter of noise. Sulu watched
> the pilot work, itching to take over. The young man glanced at him.
> "If anybody asks," he said, "you never flew this thing."
>
> "If anybody asks," Sulu said, "I've never even been in this thing."
>
> The young pilot grinned and turned over the controls.

Comment: I think you mean “a simulation” and not “an simulation.” Also we know the Star Trek space ships don’t have anti-torque pedals, but none the less, I take your “basic principles of piloting” comment.

Comment: @Doug - Cheers for that. I've edited accordingly. Also, [I think you mean "nonetheless", not "none the less".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law)

Comment: You can drive a car, but can you drive a Ford T? How long will it take for an American to learn to drive a stick shift car without instructions?

Comment: "The basic principles of piloting are, however, sufficiently similar" - I somehow doubt that an aircraft that flies based on aerodynamic principles has much in common with one that stays in the air by virtue of antigrav technology, irrespective of orientation or velocity. At least beyond "do not collide".

Comment: @O. R. Mapper - I agree with you. As I just pointed out in another comment, a student helicopter pilot might take 30 hrs to solo. So Sulu isn’t going to get coordinated with his hands and feet in just an hour to fly a Huey.  

I’ll give the writers that, under suspension of disbelief. It looks clear from this answer that he’s never seen a Huey before and he’s supposed to pick it up after learning to fly a space ship which operates via keyboard.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: that assumes he has never flown anything that doesn’t use anti-gravity, different series, but Honor Harrington like to fly hang-gliders.

Comment: Pfft. I didn't write the thing. Go yell at them

Comment: @Valorum - You're right it is "nonetheless", I just looked it up and now I know. Look at you with a relevant critique.

Comment: @Valorum - I'm not yelling at anyone. I think you answered the question. The writers are saying he's never seen one before and is supposed to pick it up in an hour or so. That's fine. It's not realistic but they travel through time, and through space faster than the speed of light in an invisible space craft. So, not being realistic seems okay to me.

Comment: Have you tried "The basic principles of piloting are… sufficiently similar that he's able to pick up the controls in a few hours…" on any real pilots? I suggest that flying a helicopter is about as far from the basic principles of piloting as piloting an aeroplane is from piloting a ship.

Comment: Sulu was established in "Shore Leave" as having an interest in 20th century firearms; it's not much of a stretch to assume he would have studied other military tech and been somewhat familiar with the controls of an antique helicopter.